# Reference not populated

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

In a `User` schema, I have a simple reference to a `Customer` schema.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  customer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Customer }, // Customer is the compiled CustomerSchema
  ...
});

const CustomerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  ...
});
```

In an Express controller, I'm fetching an user and I'm trying to embed the  customer in the returned JSON:

```
export function me(req, res, next) {
  User
    .findOne({ _id: req.user._id }, '-salt -hashedPassword')
    .populate('customer')
    .exec((err, user) => {
      if(err) return next(err);
      if(!user) return res.json(401);
      res.json(user);
    });
}
```

But in the response, `customer` is `null`.

The test data I use:

A user document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570d1f0938f7da5151b815d2"),
    "customer" : ObjectId("570d1f0838f7da5151b815d0"),
    ...
}
```

The related customer document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570d1f0838f7da5151b815d0"),
    ...
}
```

Probably a noob question, but I don't see what I don't see what I could forget =)

Comment: looks ok to me. did you wait (done callback) for your docs to be saved before populating in the query?

Comment: Yes :/
(just useless text here because SO accepts comments with 15 characters minimum xD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ref must be a string:

```
customer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer' },
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, `ref` must have a string value, which is declared when `mongoose.model(modelName: string, schema: mongoose.Schema)` is called to compile the schema into a model. Yes, that was a noob question :)